# InDesign scripts: paste into frames

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I'm working on a script which pastes my clipboard in every selected frame. After searching around I didn't figure out **how to paste something into a frame** (or polygon).

I'm stuck at something like this:

```
function pasteSelection(mySelection) {
    for (var i = mySelection.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        mySelection[i].contents = app.paste();
    }
}
```

What should `mySelection[i].contents = app.paste()` be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that will help, based on [another answer I provided not long ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796565/adobe-indesign-script-change-to-uppercase-and-copy-text-to-clipboard/45799409#45799409). For this snippet to paste anything, you MUST HAVE SELECTED TEXT in your Document. That's how this snippet know where to paste.

```
var myDoc = app.activeDocument;

if(app.documents.length != 0){
    if(app.selection.length == 1){
        try{           
            var frame1 = app.selection[0];
            frame1 = app.paste();//works
            //app.pasteWithoutFormatting(frame1);;works too
         }
        catch(e){
            alert ("Exception : " + e, "Exception");
        }
    }
 else{
    alert ("Please select text", "Selection");
  }  
}
else{
    alert("Something wrong");
}
```

Updated following comment:
For this snippet I created an indesign document into which I created 2 objects. One object is a textBox into which I typed a bunch of text, and the second item is simply just a polygon I drew below the textBox. I did not set the content type of the polygon, I simply drew the polygon. In order to effectively find the pageItems I actually want and need, I used `Script Labels`, though using labels is not mandatory. As long as you have a mechanism to know you're dealing with the right object.

The idea behind this snippet is really simple:

1. `Select the Source object`
2. `Copy the selected object`
3. `Select the Destination object`
4. `Paste into the selected object`

.

```
var myDoc = app.activeDocument;
var source;
var destination;

for(var i = 0; i < myDoc.pageItems.length; i++)
{
    if(myDoc.pageItems[i].label == "source") 
    {
        source = myDoc.pageItems[i];
        app.selection = myDoc.pageItems[i];
        app.copy();
        }
    else if(myDoc.pageItems[i].label == "destination")
    {
        destination = myDoc.pageItems[i];
        }

    if(source !== undefined && destination !== undefined)
    {
        break;
        }
}
app.selection = destination;
app.pasteInto();
```

Comment: With which command can I insert my clipboard directly **into** one polygon? E.g. I select a polygon, run the script and after that I've pasted a textframe into that polygon.

Comment: Thanks! The point was `app.pasteInto()` which I didn't know about. I was using `app.paste()`

Comment: @Malte, If you are using Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit, you can access the object model viewer with `F1` or `Help -> Object Model Viewer`. It's awful to navigate through, but most everything is there.